# PHP recursive directory menu

Tags: php, html, menu, iterator, directory

I think similar questions have been asked before, but I can't quite wrap my head around whether what I want to do is logicaly possible.

I currently use DDSmoothMenu on our intranet to list documents that we have for all staff to access.

Menu structure would be something like:

```
Documents -> Finance -> Forms -> File 1
                              -> File 2
                              -> File 3
                     -> Informational -> File 1
                                      -> File 2
          -> Insurance -> File 1
                       -> File 2
```

The basic structure of the menu is below:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Sub Menu Name</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Menu Item</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Menu Item</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Menu Item</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think it would have to involve some kind of multidimensional array and a recursive directory iterator, but I would like to go through each folder and create the HTML layout as above.

I think it may be possible to do the opening tags, but not sure how to then do the closing tags once that directory is all listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive solution could look something like:

```
function createMenuHTML($dir){
    $html = "";
    if(is_dir($dir)){
        //Directory - add sub menu
        $html .= "<li><a href='#'>Sub Menu Name</a><ul>";
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                $html .= createMenuHTML($dir.$file);
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
        $html .= "</ul>"
    }else{
        //File so  just add list item
        $html .= "<li><a href='#'>".basename($dir)."</a></li>"
    }
    return $html;
}
```

This is entirely untested but should hopefully help.

Comment: That's great, will have a play around with this and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is use trees. I recommend[Nested model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)
You can check current and perv lvl of item.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is what I ended up with thanks to Jim's example code:

```
    function createMenu($dir) {
    if(is_dir($dir)) {
        echo "<li><a href='#'>".basename($dir)."</a><ul>";
        foreach(glob("$dir/*") as $path) {
            createMenuHTML($path);
        }
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
    else {
        $extension = pathinfo($dir);
        $extension = $extension['extension'];
        echo "<li><a href='$dir'>".basename($dir, ".".$extension)."</a></li>";
    }
}

createMenu("/public/Documents");
```

Works like an absolute charm for my DDSMoothMenu, and I can be as general or as granular as I want when using the function to create the menu.

I will mark this as the answer, but Jim gave me the best starting point possible code wise!